# foreign key problem in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two functions:

```
public void Populate_flights()

public void Populate_reservations()
```

Flight and reservations are two tables.One of the entry i.e flight no. is in the reservation table. So it is a foreign key.

Now, I need to populate the database via jbdc. So I am using: In 
public void Populate_reservations() function:

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();

s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM reservations");
```

public void Populate_flights() -:

```
 Statement s = conn.createStatement();

 s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM flights");
```

So in this way, before populating the database, all my previous entries are removed and no redundant data is there.Since, there is a foreign key in reservation table, I can't delete entries from flight first. I have to remove entries from reservation first. But reservation function is called after flight function.SO how would I make it so that it will delete all the entries.

So it should be like this:

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();

  s.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");

     s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM flights");
 s.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1");
```

Answer (score 10):

You can temporary disable foreign key checks in MySQL to perform operations that would fail if these checks were enabled:

```
// Disable foreign keys check
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
stmt.close();


// Do your stuff

// Enable foreign keys check
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1");
stmt.close();
```

Note that this is a per connection setting so you have to do all your stuff using the same `conn` object.

Comment: i have to do in java...using jdbc

Comment: does it accept the word " SET". I think, it will give me the error...let me try

Comment: It should work but by only deleting the flights you end up with reservations that refer to nonexistent flights. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do but please also read @BalusC answer about cascading deletes.

Comment: @shilps Is there a good reason for the functions to be called in the order you describe? It seems that deleting the reservations first (if you can do so) would also solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to [cascade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE) the foreign key references on delete. You have to set it on the foreign key constraint. First drop the old constraint and then recreate it with the cascade instruction. Assuming that the FK name is `fk_flight`, here's an example:

```
ALTER TABLE reservations 
    DROP CONSTRAINT fk_flight;

ALTER TABLE reservations 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_flight 
    FOREIGN KEY (flight_id)
    REFERENCES flight(id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This way all referenced reservations will be deleted if you delete alone the flight.

Answer (score 2):

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();;
s.addBatch("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
s.addBatch("DELETE FROM reservations");
s.addBatch("DELETE FROM flights");
s.addBatch("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
s.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to the OP (He indirectly asks for it) to why this answer should solve his problem.

Comment: I don't know English so mush to explain why it works, but it works.