# Is there any way to run 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0 ' using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using Java 11 JDBC and MySQL Connector/J 8 jar. All other CRUDs are running OK, but when I am trying to run `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` or `SET foreign_key_checks = 1`, it shows syntax error with SQLState: 42000 and VendorError: 1064. So if there is any way to run such queries using JDBC?

```
try {
    Statement checks = connection.createStatement();
    checks.execute("set foreign_key_checks=0");
    checks.close();

    String tableName = json.getString("table");
    RowOperation rowOperation = RowOperation.valueOf(json.getString("activity"));
    JSONArray rows = json.getJSONArray("rows");

    for (Object obj : rows) {
        JSONObject row = (JSONObject) obj;
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(row.keySet());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String columns = keys.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + ",rowOperation,rowCreatedOn";
        String questionMakrs = keys.stream().map(x -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + ",?,?";
        String query = "insert into " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") values (" + questionMakrs + "); SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0";
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            String key = keys.get(i);
            stmt.setString(i + 1, String.valueOf(row.get(key)));
        }
        stmt.setString(i + 1, rowOperation.name());
        i++;
        stmt.setTimestamp(i + 1, Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
    }

} finally {
    Statement checks = connection.createStatement();
    checks.execute("set foreign_key_checks=1");
    checks.close();
}
```

Comment: How does your code looks like?

Comment: Sure.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120517/139985

Comment: But if you are getting a 1064 error, that means you have an SQL syntax error.  Hence we need to see what your code is actually doing.   It could also be that the DB user doesn't have the required rights to set session variables.

Comment: @Stephen C. I have added code snap. connection is JDBC connection object. I am getting error at first 3 lines.    Error is

Comment: SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0' at line 1
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1064

Comment: @Jens Please check code snap. Output error is added above in comment

Comment: Does the DB user doesn't have the required rights to set session variables?

Comment: Yes connected using root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute two statements, an `INSERT` followed by a `SET`, separated by a semicolon, in a single call to `prepareStatement()`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).

You must execute the `SET` statement in a separate statement.